# How to render Google Sheet Query to multiple Column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Okay, simple question, I have a data on Google Sheet like in the picture below
[image: Picture1]
How could render the data to look like in the picture below using Google Query?
[image: Picture2]

I already know basic Google Query syntax, but I can only render the data only up to the first Column by using:
*=QUERY(A1:D,"Select A,Sum(C) Where B="Red" group by B",1)*

I already try the formula above But it only can render 1 column only,
How could I make it render like in the Picture2 (Also render Blue and Yellow column)?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=QUERY(A1:D,"Select A,Sum(C) group by A pivot B",1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is actually what I was looking for!